# WSO2 Store - Method Not Allowed Error 405

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Though carbon and publisher pages are loading and I was able to successfully create and publish an API, I am not able to access the store so as to complete the next steps required.

Accessing https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/store redirects me to https://xxx./xxx./xxx./xxx:9443/carbon admin login page which allows me to successfully log in, but rather than display the store page with URL https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/store, I am getting a 405 Error Method not Allowed.

I found a few articles regarding this but nothing that seems to have fixed my issue. All logs are clear of errors but the carbon log shows successful login through the admin console before it is redirected to https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/store, where the 405 error occurs.

Comment: now I don't really know about wso2 but I know what error 405 is. It basically means that you are trying submit the wrong request to that url. For example you are trying to submit a GET request on a url that only accepts POST requests or vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using APIM 3.0.0 then the correct URL to access the developer portal is 
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443/devportal.
They have renamed the store to devportal in 3.0.0.